# Forcing Remote machine to serve RDP (or similar) session

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remote, remote-access

Due to a Dell/Nvidia design flaw in the Dell Inspiron 1420 series, my laptop no longer shows a display.  I am looking for a solution to view it remotely. I have used it via RDP in the past (not for a year though) however for what ever reason I can no longer RDP, it could have been disabled some how. However, I'm on the same LAN, I can ping it, and know its login creditials.

Is there a way I can hack into it remotely to force it to serve a RDP session or an alternative?

Please bear in mind my only view I could have to its interface is via a remote session. Its running Windows 7 Pro

Comment: Can you connect an external monitor to view the desktop? Have you tried that?

Comment: I have, and no I can't.  What I've read, the problem is something to do with electronics in the graphics card losing connection due to overheating.  The card is soldered onto the motherboard so cant replace it (or not brave enough to try). Display itself works just no picture to display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending how your firewall was set up, you could try [PSEXEC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from a computer on the same local network. It can open a cmd prompt on the remote computer and allows you to remote execute any program/script/dos cmd (even copy an app over and then execute it).

```
>psexec \\remote-computer\c$ -u ausername - apwd cmd
```

If you can connect then you can use the following to "Enable" / "Disable" RDP from that remote cmd prompt:
[Enable Remote Desktop Over a Network On Demand](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/windows-shell-bat-and-cmd/enable-remote-desktop-over-a-network-on-demand)

Here are the bat scripts from that link:

```
# To enable Remote Desktop
@reg add "\\%1\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" 
  /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

# To disable Remote Desktop
@reg add \\%1\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server 
  /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

# To check whether a computer has Remote Desktop enabled
@reg query "\\%1\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" 
  /v fDenyTSConnections
```

To execute a bat remotely, create .bat file and add one of the above cmds to it.  Move that .bat file to c:/ and open a cmd prompt and type the following:

```
>psexec \\remote-computer -u ausername -p apwd -d -c -f c:\yourbat.bat
```

Comment: I added the dos cmds above, which actually answer his question.